# QXmlQuery change node found by XPath query

Tags: c++, qt, xpath

I have a html tree and want to alter some attributes e.g. `style` of all nodes found by an QXmlQuery.

My code looks like this:

```
QXmlQuery query;
query.setFocus(data);
query.setQuery(xpathSelector);
QXmlResultItems result;
if (query.isValid()) {
    query.evaluateTo(&result);
    QXmlItem item(result.next());
    while (!item.isNull()) {
        if (item.isNode()) {
            // alter the node here <--
        }
        item = result.next();
    }

    if (result.hasError()) {
        /* Runtime error! */
    }
}
```

How can I change attributes of a node in `QXmlResultItems`?